# Onboard new infra under Puppet

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

He all
We have a puppet environment that is managing our infrastructure. 
Our environments are set as DEV, TEST and PROD. 
We manage things like users on the system, different module and applications installations and setup, OS updates etc.
Most of our configuration is the same baseline for all servers. Things that are different are written as node specifics. 
We also use "Hiera" to look up through things like nodes, environments, roles.

Our company purchased another company that already has existing infrastructure that is done manually, no automations tools. That configuration is different from our existing one.  
I was wondering, what would be the best way to onboard a new infrastructure under the puppet management?
How to organise code to now manage two different infrastructures effectively with reusable code?
There are for sure similarities that can be baselines across our existing infra and a NEW infra, but there are also a lot of specifics, like users on the systems, agent configuration etc. 
Please advise
Thanks everyone

Im doing a thorough assessment of the new infrastructure to understand its configurations.

Comment: This question is off topic here, since it's not about software development. It might be more appropriate for either [sf] or [devops.se]...except that it's also an *opinion* question, which is generally off-topic everywhere. Try transforming it into something that asks a single, well specified technical question, and post it on an appropriate site, and you'll get better answers.